# Facing a problem that I can't reach my other .html file

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am new with spring framework and I'm want to use also thymeleaf later. However, right now I just want to create a basic page where I can stright jump from one tab to another. When I start my program I can stay in 'home' page, but if I want to open other tab from nav I'm receiving an error. As I understand problem with mapping, but can't realize where's the problem.

Error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Code from Controller:

```
package com.project.project.ui.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String welcome() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/aphoto", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String add() {
        return "prideti";
    }

}
```

Code from index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Galerija</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigacija -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Galerija</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="prideti.html">Prideti nauja nuotrauka <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perziureti nuotrauku galerija <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Ieskoti" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Ieskoti</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>



<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my page where I want to get:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Galerija</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to simplify my problem I just want to hop via my website pages, but I cant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.`

Error means, you don't have html files as per controller's mapping or you did not place them on right location in project.

If you're using SpringBoot, you need to create `index.html` and `prideti.html` on path `ApplicationRoot/src/main/resources/templates/`.

Comment: Actually they are there -_-. They both are in the same folder

Comment: Can you please share project tree here?